# Jsoup exclude an element with certain attr

Tags: jsoup

How can I exclude an element which has a certain attr value from the selected elements returned from this line

```
mDocument.select("input[src*=Btn],img[src*=Btn]")
```

I need something like "which is not working"

```
mDocument.select("input[src*=Btn],img[src*=Btn]:not(img[src*=notThisOne])")
```

Thank you

Comment: post relevant parts of the source HTML please. From a first glance your selector looks fine to me, so in order to help you we need more information.

Comment: for one reason unknown to me, my code started to work fine. I am clueless as to why it did not work before.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
mDocument.select("input[src*=Btn],img[src*=Btn]").not("img[src*=notThisOne]")
```

Comment: That's fine for me then. Removing my earlier comment.